# Combining three different list in python

Tags: python, list, iteration

Thank you for looking at my issue.

I'm trying to compare cells from three csv files to make sure they are exactly the same info. the cells in the csv can contain names, dates or ID numbers. All have to match.

```
compile = []
for a in Treader,Vreader,Dreader:
    for b in a:
        compile.append(b[0])
```

However, the number of variables will fluctuate and I don't want to keep adding index splicing every time. see "complie.append(b[0])" . The question now what way can I construct this to give me a random amount of variables and random number of indexes based on the length "len" of the original list. can i use the range function for that? not sure how i can create something like this.

The current question I have is

```
List = [[sally,john,jim], [sally,john,jim], [sally,john,jim]]

If I have the list above how could I get it to show

List =[sally,sally,sally]
List1 = [john,john,john]
List2 = [jim,jim,jim]
```

Also I want to be able to come up with unlimited number of list based on the length of this list that is inside the list. In this case its 3 for three names.

Some of my list has 30 some has 5 so its important I can assign it without having to type list1 to list 30 and manually assign each one.

Comment: Can you simplify the question to exclude the excel load step? It sounds like that part is fine and you are trying to do some comparison wiht the list objects? 

I would load everything from each file into memory (it's excel so it will not be big), then get those objects into some nice state.

Also you probably just want to use pandas. Run this from an IPython REPL. You can compare table obects easily with pandas.

Comment: hope my simplification of the question is better understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use:

```
compile = list(zip(Treader,Vreader,Dreader))
```

this will create a list of tuples, a tuple will have like `(sally,john,jim)`

---

**after your edit**

you may use:

```
list(zip(*List))
```

output:

```
[('sally', 'sally', 'sally'), ('john', 'john', 'john'), ('jim', 'jim', 'jim')]
```

Comment: this is an answer I wasn't looking for but solved the exact problem differently. Thank you!!!!